# make binary (presence/absence) data matrix from multiple lists in r

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, binary, heatmap

I have a series of separate variable lists (character strings) that are different lengths. I want to combine them into one data frame to make a presence (1)/absence (0) matrix. Given that they are different lengths, I can't figure out how to even create the initial data frame. Here my example:

```
data1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
data2 <- c("e", "f", "g")
data3 <- c("a", "c", "g")
```

My final result I would like to create a binary presence/absence matrix as below so I can create a graphic (similar to a heatmap) to display this.

```
   data1     data2    data3
a    1        0         1
b    1        0         0
c    1        0         1   
d    1        0         0
e    1        1         0
f    1        1         0
g    0        1         1
```

I'm still new to R so hope my explanation is okay. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a helper function in the `splitstackshape` package called `charMat` that you might want to give a try

```
dat <- paste0("data", 1:3)
out <- t(splitstackshape:::charMat(listOfValues = mget(dat), fill = 0L))
colnames(out) <- dat
out
#  data1 data2 data3
#a     1     0     1
#b     1     0     0
#c     1     0     1
#d     1     0     0
#e     1     1     0
#f     1     1     0
#g     0     1     1
```

**data**

```
data1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
data2 <- c("e", "f", "g")
data3 <- c("a", "c", "g")
```

---

**explanation**

The function expects a `list` as first argument. We can use `mget` to create that list

```
mget(dat)
#$data1
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"

#$data2
#[1] "e" "f" "g"

#$data3
#[1] "a" "c" "g"
```

where `dat` is a character vector that contains the names of your input data

```
dat
#[1] "data1" "data2" "data3"
```

`t` is used to transpose the output of `charMat`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works, so +1, but the charMat function does not get exported when I installed splitstackshape, so I had to manually search for the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this using `%in%` which returns a logical vector if a value is present or not. Later, we use `as.integer` to convert logical value to 0 and 1.

```
# create a master list
master_list <- unique(c(data1, data2, data3))

# make sure each list is as long as master to avoid,
# this error : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
# adding 'll' just a random value
data1 <- c(data1, rep('ll', length(master_list) - length(data1)))
data2 <- c(data2, rep('ll', length(master_list) - length(data2)))
data3 <- c(data3, rep('ll', length(master_list) - length(data3)))

# create output matrix
mat <- matrix(c(as.integer(master_list %in% data1),
            as.integer(master_list %in% data2),
            as.integer(master_list %in% data3)),
            nrow = length(master_list), 
            dimnames = list(master_list))

  [,1] [,2] [,3]
a    1    0    1
b    1    0    0
c    1    0    1
d    1    0    0
e    1    1    0
f    1    1    0
g    0    1    1
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't get this to work as it creates a matrix with one column and the number of rows data1+data2+data3.    Also, this was a sample and I have 25 lists so hand-coding each one seems like not an ideal solution..